# Redux, access data inside API object with useSelector

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks, redux-thunk

I'm new to React, Redux and hooks and I'm building a simple application. First component is a search bar, you type a pokemon name, it calls an API (pokeapi)(I also use react-thunk) and returns a new component with information regarding this pokemon.

I'm building the result page component, I can console.log the state and see the whole object, but I cannot manipulate anything inside of the object.

e.g: console.log(pokemonState) returns the whole object and it's nested properties // console.log(pokemonState.name) returns undefined.

Here is my code: **App.js**

```
import { Route, NavLink, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import PokemonSearch from './container/PokemonSearch';
import PokemonResult from './container/PokemonResult';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <nav>
        <NavLink to={'/'}>Search</NavLink>
      </nav>
      <h1>TEST</h1>
      <Route path={'/'} exact component={PokemonSearch} />
      <Route path={'/pokemon/:pokemon'} exact component={PokemonResult} />
      <Redirect to={'/'} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I didn't paste it above, but the top-level index.js is wrapped by Provider as well.
**PokemonSearch.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { getPokemonData } from '../actions/pokemonAction';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import '../styles/PokemonSearch.css';

const PokemonSearch = (props) => {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const FetchData = () => {
    dispatch(getPokemonData(search));
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setSearch(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    FetchData();
    props.history.push(`/pokemon/${search}`);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="bar">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <input
            type="text"
            className="searchInput"
            placeholder="Search a Pokemon"
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </form>
      </div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PokemonSearch;
```

**Action**

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const getPokemonData = (pokemon) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: 'POKEMON_DATA_LOADING',
    });

    const res = await axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemon}`);

    dispatch({
      type: 'POKEMON_DATA_SUCCESS',
      payload: res.data,
      pokemonName: pokemon,
    });
  } catch (e) {
    dispatch({
      type: 'POKEMON_DATA_FAIL',
    });
  }
};
```

**Reducer**

```
const DefaultState = {
  loading: false,
  data: [],
  errorMsg: '',
};

const PokemonSearchReducer = (state = DefaultState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'POKEMON_DATA_LOADING':
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
        errorMsg: '',
      };
    case 'POKEMON_DATA_FAIL':
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        errorMsg: "Error: cannot find the pokemon you're looking for.",
      };
    case 'POKEMON_DATA_SUCCESS':
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        errorMsg: '',
        data: {
          ...state.data,
          data: action.payload,
        },
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default PokemonSearchReducer;
```

**Root Reducer and Store**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import PokemonSearchReducer from './PokemonSearchReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  PokemonSearch: PokemonSearchReducer,
});

export default rootReducer;

import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import { applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers/rootReducer';

const Store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk))
);

export default Store;
```

**PokemonResult.js**

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const PokemonResult = (props) => {
  const pokemonState = useSelector((state) => state.PokemonSearch);
  console.log(pokemonState.name);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PokemonResult;
```

**console.log(PokemonState) output:**
[what apis return when you type a valid pokemon name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1qus.png)

So I'm wondering what's wrong and why can I console.log the whole state but not particular properties in my component (PokemonResult)?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you put the output of console.log(pokemonState) ?

Comment: Hi Nicolas, here is a screenshot of the output: [screenshot link](https://imgur.com/a/ppGsVi8)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is multiple wrong things in your code:

you declare a default state with data = empty array

```js
// use lowerCamelCase for variable, it can be confusing as PascalCase is used for class / function component
const DefaultState = {
  loading: false,
  data: [],
  errorMsg: '',
};
```

then in your reducer the array is now an object named data that contain a data object (?) `{ data: { data: { yourpayload }, ... }`

```js
    case 'POKEMON_DATA_SUCCESS':
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        errorMsg: '',

        data: {
          ...state.data,
          data: action.payload,
        },
      };
```

then in your action getPokemonData you dispatch POKEMON_DATA_SUCCESS with pokemonName but you don't use it inside your reducer

```js
dispatch({
    type: 'POKEMON_DATA_SUCCESS',
    payload: res.data,
    pokemonName: pokemon,
});
```

and finally your useSelector select the whole state pokemonSearch so you get back `{ loading: boolean, errorMsg: string, data: { data: pokemon }}`

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const PokemonResult = (props) => {
  const pokemonState = useSelector((state) => state.PokemonSearch); // <== if you want to select pokemonData it should be state.PokemonSearch.data.data
  console.log(pokemonState.name); // <=== it should be pokemonState.data.data.name

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PokemonResult;
```

to make it cleaner and work as expected you can change the way you handle your payload inside the POKEMON_DATA_SUCCESS in your reducer:

```js
    case 'POKEMON_DATA_SUCCESS':
      // spreading state is useless here since you change all the state
      return {
        loading: false,
        errorMsg: '',
        data: action.payload,
      };
```

so then your PokemonResult component will be able to read the pokemon name by selecting the data in your PokemonSearch state:

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const PokemonResult = (props) => {
  const pokemonState = useSelector((state) => state.PokemonSearch.data);
  console.log(pokemonState.name);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PokemonResult;
```

don't forget to change your defaultState data value, it'll still work that way but it's ugly.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Nicolas, it works now and I understand my mistake. Honestly thank you for taking the time to write such a detailed explanation. I really appreciate it!

Comment: @FriedrichGLX You can check the tick and upvote the answer so people know you don't need help anymore, if you have any more question don't hesitate to ask :)

Comment: thanks, just ticked the answer. However I can't upvote yet, will do it as soon as I have enough reputation points